# Display IE ::ms-clear pseudo element in small input elements?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, pseudo-element

I have several input elements for dates and texts.
If their width is bigger than 94px the "X" ::-ms-clear is displayed but some of my inputs are smaller.

Is there a way to tell IE to display the "X" even if the input elements are only 50-60px wide? The solution should work for IE9 and higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option here is to disable the custom clear button, and provide your own. You can disable the clear button in Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge like this:

```css
::-ms-clear { display: none }
```

This will not, however, disable the custom clear button in other browsers, such as Google Chrome. In Chrome, you'll need to target a different pseudo-element:

```css
::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

The above pattern is understood by both Chrome *and Microsoft Edge*. For Internet Explorer, you will need to continue using the earlier `::-ms-clear` element as well.

With these elements hidden, we can now provide our own:

```html
<form>
    <input type="search">
    <button class="clear">&#x2715;</button>
</form>
```

We can then use *Event Delegation* to intercept click events on `.clear` at the parent `<form>`:

```js
var form = document.querySelector( "form" );

form.addEventListener( "click", function ( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ( event.target.className === "clear" ) {
        event.target.previousElementSibling.value = "";
    }
});
```

You can see the end-result online at https://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/ety8bx93/.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give this approach a try.

I assume that means it is not possible at all to get the same result by using the ms-clear element.

Comment: @PeterMueller In my initial attempts, I was unsuccessful in displaying the element when the input was few than 82px wide.